# How can I pass an object reference to a function in Javascript / jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two functions in a data tool that I'm making - `showEditDv(object)` and `editDv(object)`. If you haven't already guessed, `Dv` stands for Data Value. `showEditDv` is called when you click on the edit data icon. It generates an [Opentip](http://www.opentip.org/) tooltip that (will) allow you to edit data, and is called like this: `showEditDv(this);` in an onclick attribute. Here is the code for that function (no, there aren't inline comments in the actual thing):

```
function showEditDv(object) {
    var name = $(object).attr("data-name"); // string(name) now holds the name of the data value
    var input = new Opentip($(object), {target: null, showOn: null, hideTrigger: "closeButton"});
    input.setContent("<label>Name:</label><input type='text' value='" + name + "' class='dv-add-name' /><label>Value:</label>input type='text' class='dv-add-value' value='" + data[name] + "' /><button onclick='editDv(" + $(object) /*<-- problem */ + ");'>Apply</button>");
    input.show();
}
```

The problem arises when the `editDv()` function is called by the  'Apply' button. Because the object is being referred to in a string (I think!), the object reference is printed as `[object Object]`, and the function cannot hide the Opentip because it doesn't have a reference for it. Here is the code for `editDv()`:

```
function editDv(object) {
    var input = $(object).data("opentips")[0]; // data("opentips") is an array of objects
    input.hide();
}
```

So my question is: how can I pass the `input` object from `showEditDv` to `editDv` as an argument, or is there a better way to do this entirely?

Comment: This is a perfect reason not to use inline event handling. You already have jQuery, so use it. Create a `<button>` - `var button = $("<button>")`, set its `click` event to do exactly what you need - `button.on("click", function () { /* do whatever */ });` and use `.append()` where you need to add it somewhere.

Comment: @Ian I can't believe I overlooked that! Thanks

Comment: An immediate fix would be to pass the `id` of the element, instead of the element itself (which isn't possible in your situation, as you've found out), and then get the element by using the `id` that was just passed. It's a little easier, but not proper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't call the function inline with an onclick event, use jQuerys .on() function instead:

Like so:

```
function showEditDv(object) {
    var name = $(object).data("name"); // use .data()
    var input = new Opentip($(object), {target: null, showOn: null, hideTrigger: "closeButton"});
    input.setContent("<label>Name:</label><input type='text' value='" + name + "' class='dv-add-name' /><label>Value:</label>input type='text' class='dv-add-value' value='" + data[name] + "' /><button class='callEditDv'>Apply</button>");
    input.show();
}
```

AND

```
$('.callEditDv').on('click', function() {
    // access the button like this: $(this)
});
```

Comment: Good call, although it might be better to use `$("body").on("click", ".callEditDv", function () {  });` since these seem to be dynamic, and would avoid having to rebind the `click` event every time a new OpenTip is created